# Removing part of a filter with selects

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `angularjs` and I'm attempting to filter a table populated by an array.

In the table: `ng-repeat="item in exampleArray | filter: query"`

`query` is composed of two selects:

```
<select ng-model="query.alpha" ng-options="item for item in alphas">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="query.bravo" ng-options="item for item in bravos">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

This all works pretty well, except the initial `option` in each select, intended to mean that the select shouldn't be filtering the array.

It seems like this might be `null` rather `undefined`. I am aware of the following approach to resetting a filter: `$scope.query = {};` But this resets *every* filter, rather than just one.

How can I remove the filter from one select without resetting the whole filter?

http://jsfiddle.net/wys85kf1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter needs to know about `query.alpha` and `query.bravo`.

Please take a look on this:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items = (exampleArray | filter: query.alpha | filter: query.bravo)">
        <td>{{item.alpha}}</td>
        <td>{{item.bravo}}</td>
        <td>{{item.charlie}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Full code is available at:

> http://jsfiddle.net/wys85kf1/3/

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: This is simple and effective. Talk about a powerful pair of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bit of a PITA, and there might be a better solution available by now,

I adapted your fiddle a bit to show you 2 ways to handle this. I don't really like either, but they get the job done.

Here goes the first way:

```
ng-change='query.bravo = query.bravo ? query.bravo : ""'
```

Add that directive to your template, to the `<select>` to be precise.

And this is the second way, This is using a watch, and because of that it's even lesser prefered as the previous way.

```
$scope.$watch('query.alpha',function (newVal) {
    if (newVal === null) {
        $scope.query.alpha="";
    }
});
```

In action : http://jsfiddle.net/SanderElias/5sdfzev5/

I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the demonstration.